# How do I have differently styled labels on the same chart in LightningChart JS

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

I have a pie chart and want to have differently colored labels on each slice so that the text is more readable. Here is a slightly modified code, which creates a simple pie chart with labels inside, taken from interactive demos [here](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0451-donutChart.html?theme=darkGold&page-theme=dark):

```
const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs')

const {
    lightningChart,
    PieChartTypes,
    UIElementBuilders,
    LegendBoxBuilders,
    UIDraggingModes,
    SliceLabelFormatters,
    UIOrigins,
    emptyFill,
    emptyLine,
    Themes
} = lcjs

const donut = lightningChart().Pie({
    theme: Themes.darkGold, 
    type: PieChartTypes.LabelsInsideSlices
})
    .setTitle('Inter Hotels - hotel visitors in June 2016')
    .setPadding({ top: 40 })
    .setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    .setMultipleSliceExplosion(false)

const data = {
    country: ['US', 'Canada', 'Greece', 'UK', 'Finland', 'Denmark'],
    values: [15000, 20030, 8237, 16790, 9842, 4300]
}
const processedData = []

for (let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
    processedData.push({ name: `${data.country[i]}`, value: data.values[i] })
}

processedData.map((item) => donut.addSlice(item.name, item.value))
donut.setLabelFormatter(SliceLabelFormatters.NamePlusValue)
donut.addLegendBox(LegendBoxBuilders.HorizontalLegendBox)
    .setAutoDispose({
        type: 'max-width',
        maxWidth: 0.80,
    })
    .add(donut)
```

Is there any way to modify fill color of each slice label individually, similarly to how [setLabelFormatter](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/piechart.html#setlabelformatter) works?

If no, what are my options for doing so? I thought about creating custom UI text box element with `addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)`, though I don't know how I would position them on the slice, because I could not find any means of acquiring the slice position or any kinds of measurements (moreover, i cannot attach it to the `PieSlice` directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is (probably) no. LightningChart JS API does not provide any methods for modifying chart label styles individually for this particular type of chart. I resolved it by hiding chart labels and adding custom text boxes on top of the chart. This also requires implementing custom positioning methods on resize and slice value change.